# Best approach for implementing a reactive button in meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

Let's say I have a star/favorite button that can be pressed by a user. If they press it the button should toggle state or look different and that status should both be persistent (if I refresh the page its retains the same state) and reactive (assuming the same user had two browser instances open and they press the button, they would see the newly changed state in the other browser windw).

- Should I use an if statement in my handlebars template that selects between two different spans/divs with different different buttons?
- Would it be better to add a class to that element and have different css for buttons with that class, and somewhow push the added class back to the server and other clients?
- Some other recommended route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For it to be persistent you would need to set it in a collection to toggle the state

Your js in your click handler:

```
Template.yourtemplate.events({
    'click #yourbutton':function(event,template) {
        var state = MyCollection.findOne({}).state
        MyCollection.update({}, {$set:{state:!state}});
    }
});

Template.yourtemplate.helpers({
    item:function() {
        return MyCollection.findOne({});
    }
});
```

Then your html:

```
<template name="yourtemplate">
    {{#if yourtemplate.state}}
        <div id="yourbutton">STATE 1</div>
    {{else}}
        <div id="yourbutton">STATE 0</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Of course the above is just an example, you could use an each block helper or a different template helper to return your data. But hopefully you get the idea.

I would recommend using the if statement for two different divs (you could even just use css classes) but I wouldn't recommend using if statements or handlebars within html attributes due to the spark annotations (meteor's templating system) puts in. They're usually html comments and they don't play too well inside html attributes.

Comment: Could you please explain in layman's terms what in this query `MyCollection.findOne({}).state` `.state` is doing? `findOne()` searches for the match but what `.state` means here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ReactiveVar:

```
Template.yourtemplate.onCreated(function() {
    this.buttonState = new ReactiveVar();
    this.buttonState.set(true);
});

Template.yourtemplate.events({
    'click #yourbutton'(event,tmpl) {
        var state = tmpl.buttonState.get();
        tmpl.buttonState.set(!state);
    }
});

Template.yourtemplate.helpers({
    button_state() {
        const tmpl = Template.instance();
        return tmpl.expandedState.get();
    }
});
```

And in HTML:

```
<template name="yourtemplate">
    {{#if button_state}}
        <div id="yourbutton">STATE 1</div>
    {{else}}
        <div id="yourbutton">STATE 0</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```